# How do I setup SharePoint 2013 (On Premise) for third party apps?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have created a provider-hosted app which was developed and tested against SharePoint Online. I now want to install this on SharePoint 2013 On Premise.

It is my intention that, despite being a provider hosted app, I wish to host the app web in IIS on the SharePoint server (single farm not a cluster). I then intend to use a local URL for my App Web URL.

I understand the process of setting up an App Catalog (On SharePoint Online) as a repository for my App which in turn will enable users to add it to a site.

I have only been able to find a guide to setup On Premise SharePoint to allow users to use the SharePoint store but I only want to set it up for third party apps.

My question is do I need to go through all the steps in this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp161236.aspx even if I don't want/require store access? I don't not want to do more than necessary and I would prefer a simple solution for my clients.

I followed this guide https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp161234.aspx in the hope that creating the app catalog would be sufficient but I get the error "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps."

Comment: Hi George I want to achieve the same thing as you have already did. Can you please provide some more details about how to configure SharePoint 2013 On premise to use an App from the SharePoint online.

Do you have a link or any other help to achieve this is really really appreccited

Comment: Hi SigarDave, this is the guide I was following http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/02/13/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-aspx/ Its seems very comprehensive. I am currently trying to install on a single server farm without active directory however so I was hoping I didn't have to follow all steps. I hope this helps you though.

Comment: Thanks for the link Georgek and I will look in to it